# Can't connect to Geth node RPC from another machine

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, rpc, metamask, go-ethereum

I am running a Geth node on one machine and trying to connect to its RPC (http://127.0.0.1:8545) on my Metamask from another machine but in Metamask it always gives the following error: "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"

I can connect to that RPC just fine on the same machine that is running the node, but not the other machine.

I'm running the geth node with these parameters `geth --datadir D:\Programs\Ethereum --http`

I have already tried opening these ports in firewall on both machines inbound/outbound tcp/udp but nothing helped.

Comment: Check this out: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-expose-geths-rpc-server-to-external-connections

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a tunnel on the remote computer to connect to the local computer that geth is running on.

This should do it
ssh -N -v admin@server1 -L 8545:localhost:8545